# Any idea about the size of eclipse community?

Tags: eclipse

May be it's not the right place to ask but i don't know a better one.

I have googled to have an idea about the approximate contributors  number  of `eclispe` community but found nothing

Any body has a clue ?

Comment: define "number" in "number of `eclipse`".

Comment: by number I mean contributors

Comment: FYI: At least 2400 contributors to projects under the Eclipse Foundation steering: https://www.ohloh.net/orgs/eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This website](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse) could help you in the first place. Also [this page](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse/developers) shows a list of commiters.